# Execute API in PayPal - error 500 internal service error

Tags: service, paypal, internal

Hi i am getting this error when we call execute api in paypal.

> com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalRESTException: Error code : 500

with response:

```
{"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"28eb2ca41ee68"}
```

Please give me the solution to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide additional information about what you are trying to accomplish?

From what I can see the call is trying to execute a regular credit card payment.  However credit card payments are charged when created, or you can use the authorize then capture process to do it in 2 steps.

Execute is used if the payment uses a PayPal founding source.